# Shouldn't I use Direct Connect to deliver the solution of collecting info from multi regions in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

I came across the following question during my AWS practice and I have a different opinion and want to post it here for more discussion as it addresses a very common need, thanks.

http://jayendrapatil.com/aws-rds-replication-multi-az-read-replica/?unapproved=227863&moderation-hash=c9a071a3758c183b1cf03e51c44d2373#comment-227863

Your company has HQ in Tokyo and branch offices all over the world and is using logistics software with a multi-regional deployment on AWS in Japan, Europe and US. The logistic software has a 3-tier architecture and currently uses MySQL 5.6 for data persistence. Each region has deployed its own database. In the HQ region you run an hourly batch process reading data from every region to compute cross-regional reports that are sent by email to all offices this batch process must be completed as fast as possible to quickly optimize logistics. How do you build the database architecture in order to meet the requirements?

```
A. For each regional deployment, use RDS MySQL with a master in the region and a read replica in the HQ region
B. For each regional deployment, use MySQL on EC2 with a master in the region and send hourly EBS snapshots to the HQ region
C. For each regional deployment, use RDS MySQL with a master in the region and send hourly RDS snapshots to the HQ region
D. For each regional deployment, use MySQL on EC2 with a master in the region and use S3 to copy data files hourly to the HQ region
E. Use Direct Connect to connect all regional MySQL deployments to the HQ region and reduce network latency for the batch process
```

I lean to **E**, the reason is:

1. Direct Connect provides bandwidth that **bypasses the ISP** and more privately, faster (if needed).
2. The question doesn't factor cost here.
3. The initial setup time could be longer comparing to other options, however, initial setup time cost should not be the point here, what is asking here is “**this batch process must be completed as fast as possible to quickly optimize logistics.**”, so it is not about the initial setup, it is about how to implement the right solution to deliver the “**as fast as possible**” service **AFTER the setup**

And hence I believe **E** is the best option for the need.

I am open to discussion, please, if my understanding is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`E` is not applicable. You cannot use Direct Connect to connect 2 VPCs. Direct Connect is used to connect VPC and your premise. Question asks about multi-regional AWS infrastructure without mentioning anything about HQ not being hosted on AWS.

The easiest solution is A in my opinion.